# EF Core 2.0.1 Using IdentityUser as navigation property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When I try to register a user or create a migration I get the following error:

> "A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a
>   derived type. The key must be configured on the root type
>   'IdentityUser'. If you did not intend for 'IdentityUser' to be
>   included in the model, ensure that it is not included in a DbSet
>   property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to
>   ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation property on a type that
>   is included in the model."

I have a BaseEntity that everything derives from like so:

```
public class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CreatedById { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ModifiedById { get; set; }

        public virtual IdentityUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual IdentityUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }

public class FilePath : BaseEntity, IAuditable
    {
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a new rule or update that says you can't use IdentityUser as a navigation property? Google hasn't brought much useful information.

The entire solution is [here](https://github.com/roryaherne/RCI)
 if required.

Update: After upgrading to 2.0.1 preview, the errors are a little more helpful:

> The best match for foreign key properties {'Id' : string} are
>   incompatible with the principal key {'Id' : int}.

Comment: I think you mean 2.1 preview. Same error message, but I am using scaffolding to build my model from the database.

Comment: The `incompatible` message I believe is going to go away and it is only an `info` and not an error. I think though maybe you have an additional issue. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10918

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. You need to replace all places in code where you use BaseEntity to FilePath.

Example:
I had inheritance like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }
```

and I changed ApplicationDbContext like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

but I got the same Exception.

After I replaced IdentityUser to ApplicationUser in code the Error has gone. I reckon you should work with `BaseEntity` through `FilePath` in Data Acces Layer.

Answer (score 0):

Re. "The best match for foreign key properties {'Id' : string}..."

Your `ApplicationUser` class doesn't specify the type of its Id field. In this case it defaults to `string`. What you could do -- though this would cause you to rebuild your db so perhaps too late now -- is to explicitly type the `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser<int>
{
    // myUser.Id is now an int
}
```

[IdentityUser docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuser?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.0)